# Can't make MS Teams forget an outdated tenant ID

Tags: macos, authentication, microsoft-teams

My organisation has had trouble with Microsoft Teams authentication that grew so bad that the admin deleted the entire tenant and created a new one.

Now, whenever I try to log on to Teams with my username, it errors out with "Tenant '[old tenant ID]' not found.". I cannot choose to enter another tenant in the UI, and I can't find a way to make the app forget this outdated information.

I've already uninstalled the entire app and deleted all 'Application Support' data, globally and for my account, but no avail. I *know* that this info is stored on my computer somewhere, because I can log in on other computers - just not on the one where I actually need it, my work computer.

I *really* don't want to reinstall everything just to get my collaboration software working again. Where else could this information be stored?

Comment: This site is only for development related questions, so you'll have better luck on https://answers.microsoft.com/, but I think you can also google for resetting your Teams local cache. Sounds like a very strange issue though - good luck

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Believe it or not, I can't sign on to answers.microsoft.om for exactly the same reason. Ain't Single Sign On grand?

Comment: Sign in to that with a personal account anyway

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the secret ingredient is the **MacOS Keychain**.

Entries in this vaguely registry-like construct are distinct from either user-local or system-global Application Data, and they survive even a complete uninstall of apps. Changing its values requires opening the "Keychain Access" app (usually semi-hidden in the 'Other' apps group).

I managed to make MS Teams forget my previous identity only by deleting *all* "login items/Passwords" entries named anything like "Microsoft". (Still looking for the equivalent solution on iOS, though.)